# How do Post with jquery such that redirect from the server will be properly rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
$j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://acme.host.vhost/objects/create/',
        dataType: 'http',
        async: false,
        data: {object: data},
        success: function (msg) {
            // window.location = 
            alert(msg);
        },
        statusCode:{
            200: function(){
                alert(200);
            }
        }
    });
```

In inspector, I see that the response is an entire web page. How do I change my POST request so that the browser will actually be redirected to that web page?

the alert(200) happens, so.. everything is ok? but success: isn't triggered. =\

Answer (score 1):

ajax works like a "secondary browser", which it sends requests, receives it - and it stops there. it does not touch your browser display until you parse what's in it (and do whatever things that follow).

what you can do is to create your own standard of knowing when to redirect, or more generally, how the server communicates it's commands to the client side. I preferably use JSON to do this, sending commands from the server to the client like:

```
{
    "errors": [],   //an array of all errors from the server (like validation and stuff)
    "details": [    //an array of additional details the client side must kno
        "redirect": "url_here.html"
    ],  
    data: {}      //the actual payload of the request. may be html, or further data or templates etc.
}
```

one of my apps return a JSON object with the `details` property to:

- know what page of a search result i am in
- how many it contains
- what was the search query

and so on..

so instead of returning (or in this case "echoing") the result page in HTML, use JSON to forward the user to a "success" page instead.